# Features NVZ takes more time to load on map

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

- Features NVZ takes more time to load on map
- I am fetching data from Layer:
  https://environment.data.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/EA/NitrateVulnerableZones2017Final/FeatureServer/0
- I am using arcgis javascript api 4.14 version
- If I zoom in the map on zoom level 6 then only this NVZ features are
  displaying on map, but its taking more time to load on map.
  [image]

Here is my code:-

```
var map;
require([
    "esri/widgets/Sketch",
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/geometry/Polygon",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/Graphic",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/Color"
],
function(Sketch, Map, GraphicsLayer, MapView, Polygon, FeatureLayer, SimpleLineSymbol, Graphic, SimpleFillSymbol, Color) {
const layer = new GraphicsLayer();
const map = new Map({
    basemap: "streets",
    layers: [layer]
});


const view = new MapView({
    container: "map",
    map: map,
    zoom: 5,
    center: [-3.118092, 54.509865]
});

// set dynamic url for feature layer
function initOperationalLayer() {
    var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://environment.data.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/EA/NitrateVulnerableZones2017Final/FeatureServer/0",{
        mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        map.add(featureLayer);
    });
}
 initOperationalLayer();
});
```

Comment: Just from copy&paste of your code into an IDE to format shows you have massive syntax errors in your `initOperationalLayer` function, those red squiggles are all over it, probs extending further, many of your braces have no close - this is incomplete code, please add the rest

Comment: What is more time?, have you compare it with the mapviewer? .. When I check it in the viewer it do takes some time to render, but it seems to me that is just a heavy layer. There are not "many" features but each have a lot of points.

Comment: From a quick look it seems the FeatureService is slow to respond, the Network tab in the Chrome DevTools shows me response times greater than 10s from the service.